# manage bare git repos using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am not sure if there is a good way to manage git repos on server using puppet. Basically, if i was to do it via bash commands, it would be:

```
cd -gitdir-
git init --bare
```

I want to set everything up so that the team can push to the server. Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Say you've got a variable `$reponame`, maybe inside a [defined type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/definedtypes.html) if you want to manage multiple repos:

```
exec { "init_repo_$reponame":
    command => "/usr/bin/git init --bare /path/to/repos/$reponame",
    creates => "/path/to/repos/$reponame",
}
```